# issues with navbar links not collapsing

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

firstly apologies opening a question on which should be seen as a fairly simple issue....and it should be, but I cant get it working to save my life.

Maybe someone can just give this code a quick scan and tell me what I am doing wrong, as I am not to familiar with bootstap (which im using here) and HTML5

**My Problem**

Navbar working perfectly on home page but when copy and pasting navbar to other pages the `services` and `menu` links simply do not expand / collapse

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Finger Food Catering</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="hot-food-platters.html">Hot Platters</a></li>
            <li><a href="cold-finger-food-platters.html">Cold Platters</a></li>
            <li><a href="gourmet-finger-food-platters.html">Gourmet Platters</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Services<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="wedding-catering.html">Wedding Catering</a></li>
            <li><a href="birthday-catering.html">Birthday Catering</a></li>
            <li><a href="corporate-catering.html">Corporate Catering</a></li>
             <li><a href="special-event-catering.html">Event Catering</a></li>
            <li><a href="funeral-catering.html">Funeral Cateringg</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
        <li><a href="inquire.html">Inquire</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
         <li class="active"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span style="font-size:2.0em"><span style="color:#8AB8E6">Contact Us:</span> <body onload="_googWcmGet('number', '1300 785 701')">
    <span class="number">1300 785 701</span>
  </body> </a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Using bootstrap? If yes, did you link JQuery and Bootstrap.js?

Comment: @XahedKamal ofcourse I did, but thanks for input

Comment: is this http://jsbin.com/sawejawate/1/edit?html,output behaviour the correct one? Just look into your services and menu files and look if you maybe miss a closing "div" somewhere. That is often causing some issues.

Comment: duplicates of bootstrap.js loading? Loading it twice or perhaps at the wrong stage of the page will cause problems. Duplicate ID's may also cause problems. Missing end tags? Hard to tell from this partial code really..

Comment: Why do you have an extra `body` element inside `ul.navbar-right`?

Comment: Can you please give us a link to the actual website if it is live? Really need to see how the resources are linked to the pages.

Comment: @Nerdwood that is for google adwords when user calls they get forwarded to google adsense which directs call to us to track conversions

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [Materialize](http://materializecss.com)?

If you are, scroll down to the bottom of index.php where the scripts are and change `<script src="../../bin/materialize.js"></script>` to `<script src="js/materialize.js"></script>`